# Microsoft Graph: "Unknown Error" when calling /contacts

Tags: azure, active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal

In Graph Explorer, when logged in as a user from my application (the user has admin rights, I used the same user to set the admin consent) I am trying to call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts` and all I am getting is `Unknown Error`. And the text prompt that suggests I have a problem with permissions.

It works fine with the demo tenant. Same thing happens when I try to call the API from code with an admin token.

Here are the permissions for the application:

[image: Permissions]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. It isn't clear what error you're getting. Without the code you're using to call the API as well actual result you're getting back, it could be almost anything.